# MustUnderstand headers Error trying to get session in Apache Chemistry

Tags: java, cmis, apache-chemistry

I'm trying to get a session with Apache Chemistry, and it throws me this exception:

```
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: Error: MustUnderstand headers:[{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.webservices.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfo(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:131)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfo(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.connect(SessionImpl.java:1051)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.createSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:106)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.createSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:68)
    at com.ecm.dev.testCmis.TestCmis.before(TestCmis.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: MustUnderstand headers:[{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood
    at com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.MUTube.createMUSOAPFaultException(MUTube.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube.processResponse(ClientMUTube.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1147)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:463)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:191)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.getRepositoryInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.webservices.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfo(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:127)
    ... 28 more
```

I'm trying to get the session in the webservices binding type, but that happen, in the atompub way it works ok,

Comment: What version of OpenCMIS are you using? What repository are you trying to connect to? And are you connecting to a CMIS 1.0 or a CMIS 1.1 endpoint?

Comment: @Gagravarr the version of apache chemistry is the 0.13.0, the repository is EMC Documentum 7.1 with CMIS Version 1.0 :)

Comment: You should probably edit that into your question. (That's not a stack I know, so I can't help, sorry)